# Association with multiple records in one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, nested-forms

i need your help to link multiple records (here countries) with an other record (here policy) in same time into a form (new policy).

My models like :

```
class Retailer < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :orders
   has_many :policies, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Policy < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :countries
end

class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :orders
    has_many :users
    has_one :platform
end
```

What i want is to link my new policy when i create this one in his form with multiple countries.

I want to use check boxes into this form to check what country i link (all countries stored in DB will be there).

I dont know if my association is appropriate for this context but i am bit lost how to do it.

Can someone help how to accomplish this and show me how my view should be ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I use rails 4 version @BroiSatse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What i want is to link my new policy when i create this one in his
>   form with multiple countries.

You want to set a `belongs_to :country` in your `policy` model instead of `has_many :countries`

```
class Policy < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :country
end
```

and `has_many :policies` in your `country` model

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :orders
    has_many :users
    has_one :platform
    has_many :policies
end
```

> I want to use check boxes into this form to check what country i link
>   (all countries stored in DB will be there).

For this,you can use **[collection_check_boxes](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes)**.By setting like above(`belongs_to :country`),you will get `country_id` which you will be using with `collection_check_boxes` to `check/uncheck` the multiple countries.

Hope it helps!

**Update**

Might i have just wrong with the associations.In your case,it is a **[has_and_belongs_to_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)**.

```
class Policy < ActiveRecord::Base

has_and_belongs_to :countries

end

class Country < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :orders
has_many :users
has_one :platform
has_and_belongs_to_many :policies

end
```

Comment: @Ithy Ofcourse you are right!You want one policy with one country or one policy with many contries?

Comment: One policy with many countries and do it in the same form. @pavan

Comment: @Ithy Have a try with it.I think you can able to check multiple countries.